# Ajax laravel 5.2 doesn't work

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I want to develop simple ajax with laravel5.2  with this code

This oneline_help.php view

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Ajax Example</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         function getMessage(){
            $.ajax({
               type:'POST',
               url:'/getmsg',
               data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
               success:function(data){
                  $("#msg").html(data.msg);
               }
            });
         }
      </script>

</head>
<body>
      <div id = 'msg'>This message will be replaced using Ajax. 
         Click the button to replace the message.</div>
      <?php
         echo Form::button('Replace Message',['onClick'=>'getMessage()']);
      ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

This is the routes

```
Route::get('/ajax','front@support');
Route::post('/getmsg','Hello@index');
```

This is front @support

```
public function support() 
{
    return view('online_help', array('title' => 'Welcome', 'description' => '', 'page' => 'online_help','subscribe'=>"",'brands' => $this->brands));
}
```

This is Hallo @index controller

```
public function index(){
       echo"i in in hello index";
      $msg = "This is a simple message.";
      return response()->json(array('msg'=> $msg), 200);
   }
```

The button appear But when click on it, The text doesn't change  .
Please tell me why and how to resolve it.

Comment: Try to remove `echo"i in in hello index";` in your controller method !

Comment: I remove but the same text doesn't change

Comment: can you check that what response you get in you debugger console ?

Comment: I use xampp and browser  .How to display debugger console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working example of AJAX....

You don't need to add `token` in your ajax request, make it global so with every ajax request, your `CSRF token` will be added automatically.

In your **HTML Head** section add this meta tag

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="<?php echo csrf_token() ?>">
```

Then add this code in your Javascript tags. this will add CSRF token in every ajax request.

**Note** this required jquery file should be included in your page. once include call this method below from the file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var csrf_token   =   $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    $.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {"X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrf_token}
    });
</script>
```

**I have modified your method....**

```
  <script>
     function getMessage(){
        $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'/getmsg',
           data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>', //remove this line
           dataType:'json', // you skipped this line
           beforeSend:function(){
              alert('loading....'); //this will show loading alert
           },
           success:function(data){
              $("#msg").html(data.msg);
           },
           error:function(){
              alert('loading error...')
           }
        });
     }
  </script>
```

Comment: I tried your answer.loading and loading alert displayed  but the text not changed

Comment: I add <meta....>in the head of the page  and  add <script type="text/javascript">.......in the footer of the page    Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, Its correct.... 
can you tell me what response you are getting in you console ?

Comment: When   write http://localhost/larashop/public/support  in my browser  I get the button when I click on it to change the text ,the two alert message displayed load then error load and the the text not changes .

Comment: which web browser you are using ? install Firebug tool in your browser to trace the issue.

Comment: I download firebug tool.At first I found error getmsg not found.When I remove / from         url:'/getmsg',  I found 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your Routes... Please check

Comment: The problem was in controllers when I deal with one controller it works.